# error: @synthesize

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my AppDelegate.h file i written the following code

```
@interface iBountyHunterAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UITabBarController *tabcontroller;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabcontroller;
```

and in AppDelegate.h file I synthesize it.

```
@synthesize tabcontroller;
```

but in @synthesize line i get an error and the msg is: "MISSING CONTEXT FOR PROPERTY IMPLEMENTATION DECLARATION"

can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: You don't need this part: ` { UITabBarController *tabcontroller; }`. That part is generated automatically by @synthesize. See also MaciejK answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you have put the `@synthesize` outside of your @implementation.  It should look something like this

```
//  iBountyHunterAppDelegate.m

#import "iBountyHunterAppDelegate.h"

@implementation iBountyHunterAppDelegate

@synthesize tabcontroller; // note that this is between @implementation and @end

// other stuff

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

"and in AppDelegate.h file I synthesize it." Probably it´s just misspelled but it has to be in .m file :P

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface iBountyHunterAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 

{

    UITabBarController IBOutlet *tabcontroller;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabcontroller;
```

and in `AppDelegate.h` file I synthesize it.

```
@synthesize tabcontroller;
```

Answer (score 0):

synthesize your property in controller(iBountyHunterAppDelegate.m) file instead of interface(.h) file